# Weird blank character behaviour in regex C

Tags: c, regex

I have a problem using regex in C.
I want to collect a command (GET, PUT or DEL) and a filepath, to send the right command to a server.

If I compile only `' [[:blank:]]*(GET|PUT|DEL|HELP) '`, the code works and I collect the right thing. However, when I add something to the expression, such as : `'[[:blank:]]*(GET|PUT|DEL|HELP)[[:blank:]]+([a-z])'`, the regexec returns REG_NOMATCH.

Do you have a solution or do you know why?

This is my code:

```
#include <regex.h>
#include "dgb.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <stdio_ext.h>

DEFINE MODE "client"

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

    regex_t preg;
    const char *str_regex = "[[:blank:]]*(GET|PUT|DEL|HELP)[[:blank:]]+([a-z])";
    char str_request[51];
    int reg_init;
    int reg_request;
    size_t nmatch = 0;
    regmatch_t *pmatch = NULL;       

    reg_init = regcomp(&preg, str_regex, REG_ICASE);

    if (reg_init != 0) {
        printf("Error\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    nmatch = preg.re_nsub;
    pmatch = malloc(nmatch * sizeof(*pmatch));
    checkmem(pmatch);

    while(strcmp(str_request,"quit") != 0) {

        printf(">>");
        scanf("%50s", str_request);
        __fpurge(stdin); //fpurge on OSX

        reg_request = regexec(&preg, str_request, nmatch, pmatch, 0);

        if (reg_request == REG_NOMATCH) {
            printf("%s: Invalid command, please tap help\n", MODE);
        }

        else if (reg_request == 0) {

            char *cmd = NULL;
            int start = pmatch[0].rm_so;
            int end = pmatch[0].rm_eo;
            size_t size = end - start;

            cmd = malloc (sizeof (char*) * (size + 1));
            strncpy(cmd, &str_request[start], size);
            cmd[size] = '\0';
            printf ("%s\n", cmd);


            free(cmd);    
         }   
    }

    free(pmatch);        
}
```

Comment: It seems to be a `regex` problem, not a `C` problem... Therefore perhaps you should get rid of all the `C` stuff which makes your question more complicated that it should be

Comment: On which string are you getting this `REG_NOMATCH` ?

Comment: Does this complicated expression need `REG_EXTENDED`?

Comment: Do you intend to match more than one lowercase letter? use ([a-z]+)

Comment: You're right, I don't need REG_EXTENDED flag.
For example when I test with GET file or GET f, the return is a nomatch...

Comment: @Jongware: `REG_EXTENDED` switches over to ERE syntax. In this case, it is important, since the regex doesn't adhere to BRE syntax.

Answer (score 1):

There are two problems here:

1. Format string `%s` in `scanf` extracts a string of non-whitespace characters and stops at the first whitespace character found. When you input `GET something`, only `GET` is read by the `scanf` line.

   ```
   scanf("%50s", str_request);
   ```

   One option is to change the code to use `fgets` to read the whole line of input. Do note that the new line character is included in the buffer, so you have to deal with it accordingly.
2. You are writing your regex in Extended Regular Expression (ERE) syntax, since you are using alternation `|`, grouping `(` and `)`, one or more quantifier `+`.

   In Basic Regular Expression (BRE), `|` and `+` is not available, and the parentheses must be escaped `\(` `\)` to invoke its special meaning.

   Therefore, the `REG_EXTENDED` flag is necessary to make your regex works as intended.

#### Reference

- [Regular Expressions - POSIX standard](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap09.html)

Answer (score -1):

There are missing characters in your regex for the path spec. Since it starts with a `/` you get a match failure.
Try replacing `[a-z]` with `.+`

Comment: Yes, but it does not work even if I try to match only "blabla", without the /