# Why does C not catch any substrings when matching with a regular expression

Tags: c, regex

I am trying to use POSIX to match a regular expression (I can't use pcre unfortunately). But when I put parentheses around  the sub string I want to catch, the program is trying to match the parentheses.
How can I catch the actual substring that I want

This is my code

```
recomp(&regex_withdraw, "^withdraw ([0-9]+)$", 0);
if(regex(&regex_withdraw, command, 2, groupArray, 0) == 0){
    printf("withdraw %s dollars\n", groupArray[1].rm_eo - groupArray[1].rm_so);
}
```

The above code matches to

```
withdraw (4)
```

but not

```
withdraw 4
```

And in neither case can I actually get the substring I need (in this case 4)
And using the REG_EXTENDED flag is not changing the behavior

*EDIT

I tried using

```
recomp(&regex_withdraw, "^withdraw \([0-9]+\)$", 0);
```

As recommended by responses but the program is still experiencing the same behavior

Comment: If that's like vim or sed regexes, try with `\(` and `\) `.

Comment: And please write a complete small program and include that in your questions. Makes it easier to test.

Comment: This needs the EXTENDED regex flag. A plain dup of http://stackoverflow.com/q/30828786/2564301 but alas that has no *accepted* answer. It's also mentioned in several Posix flavor regex manuals.

Answer (score 2):

POSIX basic regexs use `\(`...`\)` for capture groups, with unescaped parens matching literally -- basically the opposite behavior from PCRE and EXTENDED regexes.

Note that in order to get `\` characters into a C string literal, they need to be escaped with `\`.  So add `\\` before the `(` and `)` and it should work.

Comment: Thats not working for me it still matches to withdraw (4) and not withdraw 4